# Get sum of a column after and before of a date?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to fetch the sum of quantities after and before a date from a table.

This is what I tried:

```
select location_id, t1.product_id, sum(t1.quantity) as open, 
       t2.product_id as t2_p,sum(t2.quantity) as current
from (select id, location_id, product_id, quantity
      from stock_history 
      where date::date<='2018-09-23') t1
FULL OUTER JOIN (select id, product_id, quantity
                 from stock_history 
                 where date::date>'2018-09-23') t2
    ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id
group by location_id, t1.product_id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation

```
select location_id, product_id,
    sum(case when date::date>'2018-09-23' then quantity end) as current,
    sum(case when date::date<='2018-09-23' then quantity end) as open
from stock_history
group by location_id, product_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `case` expressions to do conditional aggregation:

```
select id, location_id, product_id,
       sum(case when date::date <= '2018-09-23' then quantity end),
       sum(case when date::date >  '2018-09-23' then quantity end)
from stock_history
group by id, location_id, product_id,
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need a join there. The `FILTER` clause of aggregates can be helpful:

```
SELECT location_id,
       product_id,
       sum(quantity) FILTER (WHERE date::date <= '2018-09-23') AS open,
       sum(quantity) FILTER (WHERE date::date >  '2018-09-23') AS current
FROM stock_history
GROUP BY location_id, product_id;
```

Comment: Could you explain the difference between `FILTER` and 'Case'?

Comment: The effect is the same, it is just easier to read (in my opinion). It may also be slightly faster, but that is probably not measurable.

Comment: Case is core ANSI SQL and very portable. Filter is less portable, but also ANSI SQL.

Comment: If portability is a concern, I agree. I think readability in SQL queries is important - I have stared at huge impenetrable SQL statements too often.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, seems to be an ANSI SQL extension "_13) Without Feature T612, “Advanced OLAP operations”, conforming SQL language shall not contain a
<filter clause>._" (SQL-2016 spec, page 807.)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe . . . I think `filter` is measurably faster, because it discards the data before the aggregation function is attempted -- and under some circumstances, it might be able to use indexes.  I don't think the gain is big, something like 20%, but I have seen comparisons where it is measurable.